# Remove new 'Selector' left toolbar in Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

At some point this year a new toolbar turned up in Adobe Reader -

[image]

This gets in the way of my opened documents often, is this possible to remove? I have looked but can't find it!

I am using v2023.003.20244

Comment: Workaround: there are many free Adobe reader alternatives, some with a simpler interface, such as Sumatra PDF, https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader, or powerful PDF-XChange Editor, https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor, which does allow the overly-complex GUI to be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to View>Disable new Acrobat Reader

Comment: Oh my gosh @Tini, hallelujah!! I did not expect this, thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have Adobe Reader on several machines and Acrobat on one machine.

The sidebar you see is the new Adobe way forward. Other Apps do the same thing.

You can collapse the tools menu and the selector goes to the left side and provides more document space, but it is not removable.  I think you collapsed the tool menu in your screenshot.

The Menu in your screen shot is the top left hamburger icon.

Once changed, you cannot change it back. It is just the way it is.

You can try entering Adobe Feedback, but I have found that falls on deaf ears.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this feedback John!